# CsQuery: losing nested html-Tag after manipulating InnerText

Tags: c#, nested, innerhtml, csquery

I am using CsQuery in a C# Project.
As a simple example I have a p-Tag which has a nested b-Tag in it:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sanctus <b>TEST</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

I need to modify the plain-text in each Tag, meaning the text inside the p-Tag and inside the b-Tag, with another method (louis()):

```
IDomObject htmlelement = dom.Get(i);
if (!(htmlelement.FirstElementChild == null))
{
    string test = htmlelement.InnerHTML;
    //test: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sanctus <b>TEST</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    STDIN = htmlelement.FirstElementChild.InnerText;
    OUTPUT = louis(command, param, STDIN);
    htmlelement.FirstElementChild.InnerText = OUTPUT;

    STDIN = htmlelement.InnerText;
    OUTPUT = louis(command, param, STDIN);
    htmlelement.InnerText = OUTPUT;
    test = htmlelement.InnerHTML;
    //test now loses the nested <b>TEST</b>
    //test: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sanctus  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
}
```

When I try to replace (only) the text inside the p-Tag with the new text, the nested b-Tag is lost. How can I prevent this and I'm sure there is a better way to manipulate nested Elements since it is a powerful framework. I just haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug in the release version of CsQuery for `InnerText`... see https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/issues/82

Either use the `Text()` method, which is a `CQ` method so you'd need to wrap the element in a `CQ` object, e.g.

```
STDIN = htmlelement.FirstElementChild.Cq().Text();
```

..or update to the current prerelease version 1.3.5 beta 5 on nuget which fixes this problem: http://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/1.3.5-beta5

Humblest apologies that this has remained so long in the release version which is a year old now!

Comment: Alright thanks for clearing that up and keep up the great work! Much appreciated!